# According to Google Analytics 80% of my visitors are "direct", but I suspect that isn't true, what can I do?

Tags: google-analytics, traffic, referrer

I have a small site representing a software hosted on github.io domain. I use Google Analytics. For the last week or so, I get this statistics at the user acquisition tab:

```
                  Visits
Direct             96
Social             10
Organic Search     4 
Referral           4
```

[image: image description]

But I'm quite sure I'm getting most traffic from other sites, mostly the project repository on github.com. I think I am doing something wrong when working with the data. How do I see where the people came from and how many?

Comment: Most common reason is that a bunch of visitors come from an `https` page to your `http` page. Than the referrer should not be set and they appear as direct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your website is not `https` and since most traffic comes from github.com, which has `https`, the referrer will not be set.

You can read it on the [RFC page](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2)

> A user agent MUST NOT send a Referer header field in an
> unsecured HTTP request if the referring page was received with a
> secure protocol.

Comment: Ah... well yeah. My site uses javascript to redirect to `http` variant because `https` protocol was problematic and there's nothing to secure on the site.

Comment: @TomášZato - yes - good thing is now I know it for my own site as well. Because the directs were kinda high to my expectations. Feel free to mark my answer as correct, if it clearified everything ;)